# Edit Page Content not showing

Tags: pages, author

I want to edit some pages, already built but I am unable to edit their content (Content is not showing). Although I have Administrator role/rights but not been able to edit pages those are built by other authors (not Administrator).
I have tried to edit pages by logging IN by other authors but not been successful.
Is there someone who can guide me in this process?

Comment: So, the content is not showing in the WSIWYG editor? if thats true, is the content in any of the template files?

Comment: This question seems very localized, meaning given the information it would be pretty difficult to answer. Have you [enabled debugging](https://codex.wordpress.org/Debugging_in_WordPress) ( both display and log )? Do you have any errors in your javascript console?

Comment: Yes, content is not showing in editor. And there is no content in any of template files as well. Actually Website pages are already built by someone, and I want to edit some pages content.
I am site Administrator and have Administrator rights.
Some pages have been built by administrator and I can edit content of these pages successfully. But some pages built by another author and I am unable to edit content of these pages, In other words, content of these pages not been shown.